# SDL Access violation writing location 0x02a251c8

Tags: location, sdl, access-violation

I've read through every access violation writing location question on here I could find, and maybe I'm missing something, but I seem to be experiencing a different error. I've initialized all my pointers (as far as I can tell).

```
void putpixel( SDL_Surface* surface, int x, int y, Uint32 pixel )
{
    int k = GetWidth(surface);
    //Convert the pixels to 32 bit
    Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32 *)surface->pixels;

   //Set the pixel
    pixels[ ( y * surface->w ) + x ] = pixel; //This is the line the debugger points to.
}
```

The program displays the Mandelbrot Set. This is the function I was using to access pixel data. When I first wrote the program, it was all in int main() and it worked fine using this very function. I intended to write this as an exercise using SDL and pointers, so I split it up and made Mandelbrot its own class to learn a bit about OOP. Only once I split it up did I start having these problems. Is there something obvious I'm missing? I'd be happy to post the rest of the code, I just don't want to inundate you guys with code that is irrelevant. When I trace the problem back it points to the putpixel function in the actual code for drawing the set, which makes sense. Could the problem have originated there?

EDIT: Scratch that. I did some error handling and I'm definitely locking the surface correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Care of manipulating the data directly, depending the type of the surface, you need to [SDL_LockSurface](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdllocksurface.html)/SDL_UnlockSurface.

In case that is not changing anything to your access location error, check/print the value for `y`, `surface->w` and `x`

Comment: See my edit. I think I'm locking the surface correctly but I feel like I'm making a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I'm a complete idiot. The reason I was getting this error was because I was exceeding the bounds of the array of pixels. The issue came from how I defined my function that set the parameters of the set. I was setting height as width and width as height. I knew it was something obvious. Let this be a lesson to other newbie programmer like myself. If you get a weird cryptic error like this, examine the simple stuff. An oversight like this can cost you a lot of time.